# How to prevent a spritesheet from showing other sprites during resize

Tags: html, css, sprite-sheet

I want to make a rotating image gallery out of a sprite sheet.  I basically want to rotate through two images that are stacked on top of each other.

I would like this gallery to be responsive, and flexible, as a percentage of the windows width.

However, I am realizing that if I set the `background-size` to `100%` (in order to make the sprites fill the containing `div`, upon resizing the browser window, the other sprites contained in the sprite sheet will show through.  I can not figure out the settings to make a fully responsive background-image using sprites.

Here is where I am so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="imageone" class="sprite"><div>
<div id="imagetwo" class="sprite"><div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
   width: 50%;
}

.sprite {
    background-image url('../images/gallery_sprite.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Scrolling (resizing the window) lets the others sprites show. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: this may be a [useful article](http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/responsive-background-image-sprites-css-tutorial/)